# Makefile export variable for triggering prerequisite

Tags: makefile, export

this is my makefile piece of code I would like to understand better why it does NOT work:

```
.PHONY: main_rule
main_rule: export MAIN=1
main_rule: main_prereq
    ... some stuff here ...


.PHONY: main_prereq
main_prereq: $(if $(filter 1,$(MAIN)),true_cond,false_cond)
    ..... other stuff here ...

.PHONY: true_cond
true_cond: 
    ..... other stuff here ...

.PHONY: false_cond
false_cond: 
    ..... other stuff here ...
```

My problem in on the "export MAIN=1". I suppose that the main_prereq was able to execute true_cond, instead it is not exported to the pre-requisite list.

The reason I am using the export is because main_prereq can be called by other rules, so I need something to differentiate the execution (true_cond only for main, else false_cond for all the others).

Even if you have better solutions for my problem , I kindly ask to you to help me to understand why it does not work (I think I didn't catch all the makefile philosophy).

Answer (score 1):

To cite from the GNUmake manual:

> A rule is always expanded the same way, regardless of the form:
>
> ```
> immediate : immediate ; deferred
>     deferred
> ```

The second `immediate` refers to the prerequisite list - this one is evaluated in the first phase (the second phase is the "execution" phase where the recipes are run for real, existing targets) for normal rules, therefore the value of `$(MAIN)` is not set at the time `make` evaluates the `filter` expression - target specific variables are set only during the second phase. In your case `SECONDEXPANSION` should do the trick:

```
.PHONY: main_rule
main_rule: export MAIN=1
main_rule: main_prereq
    ... some stuff here ...

.SECONDEXPANSION:  # from here on all rules will be expanded a second time
                   # all $-denoted values will be evaluated the first time,
                   # so we need to quote $$ everything we want to have evaluated 
                   # only the second way round
.PHONY: main_prereq
main_prereq: $$(if $$(filter 1,$$(MAIN)),true_cond,false_cond)
    ..... other stuff here ...

.PHONY: true_cond
true_cond: 
    ..... other stuff here ...

.PHONY: false_cond
false_cond: 
    ..... other stuff here ...
```

Comment: We could also move the `true_cond` and `false_cond` rules before `.SECONDEXPANSION:` as they apparently don't need to be expanded twice.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you reply, I actually found your solution in another thread, but it doesn't work for me. I also moved the SECONDEXPANSION exactly to be the only piece of code to be expanded, but nothing.

Comment: Which version of `make` are you using? Also, you can output the target line via a `$$(info $$$$(if $$$$(filter 1,$$(MAIN))...`  at the very place where the `$$(if..)` is, to see what is really being executed there.

Comment: Gnu 3.82.
I also did what you suggested, the output is actually ok (the rule is good). I also outputted `$$(info $$(if $$(filter 1,$$(MAIN)),true_cond,false_cond) - $$(MAIN))` and I got two call: `false_cond -` and `true_cond - 1`, but the secodn stamp seems to be later than the rule execution (Even if I should not rely on output shell ordering).
What do you think? It seems to be ok as well :(

Comment: Is there any possible way to upgrade to a modern version? I don't know the behaviour of 3.82 re: target specific variables, especially if it is bugfree. You can test execution order by relying on `$(info)`: simply put a `echo $(info Got here!)` in the recipe. The `$(info)` will be executed after prerequisite evaluation and before recipe execution.

Comment: Well, actually I cannot, since I'm working on a server and I do not have rights to upgrade.
Anyway, since this way seems to be impracticable, do you have any other idea to overcome the problem? My current solution was to move the main_prereq inside the main_rule recipe and executing it with `make main_prereq`. In that case, the MAIN flag is correctly set. I do not like this solution, do you have others? Thank you